# Rules changes with CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE does not work

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I am trying to limit gitlab to run a job only when the trigger is a merge request or subsequent pushes to the source branch.

Below is my gitlab-ci yaml
[image]

But even if i change gilab-ci.yaml the pipeline triggers, also it runs when i change the test-file.sh file inside awe/src/.

I tried it to trigger a downstream-pipeline using these rules, it didn’t work. I also tried to run a local script as well. But no luck.

The rules config

[image]

I also tried to add the source as push event since sometimes the subsequent commits to a branch with an active MR is treated as push event

In all scenarios, the pipeline triggers everytime i make a change, irrespective of whether the change is made to the folder specified or not.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To limit the execution to only certain scenarios like `push` or `merge request` you need to add an `if` condition:

```
rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
```

One thing to be aware of is that you cannot mix `only` and `rules` in the same job, as the docs state

> rules replaces only/except and they can’t be used together in the same job. If you configure one job to use both keywords, the GitLab returns a key may not be used with rules error.

Refer to [this link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules) for a commonly used set of `rules` that is provided in the documentation and may be helpful for you.

Comment: I did try with rules and rules:changes  and added the if condition you mentioned as well, which also does not work. It runs irrespective of my setting

Comment: You should update your answer with the latest config you've attempted and what you're seeing when the pipeline triggers, so we're able to help in a better way